# Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT)) C#

Tags: c#

Recently when I run this code I get the following error `Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))`. I have only recently started getting this issue. Basically when I run this code it checks if an addin is disabled if so then enable it. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error now.

My code is as follows

```
        foreach (COMAddIn currentAddIn in myApp.COMAddIns)
        {
            if (currentAddIn.ProgId == "Create.ExcelAddIn" && !currentAddIn.Connect)
            {

                    currentAddIn.Connect = true;
            }
       }
```

Comment: Usually errors start with 0x8 are invalid memory pointers/addresses.  The object could be null or pointing to an address outside the application.

Comment: @jdweng thank for answering. My object appears to be null. I'm unsure why this is as it has been working all along. Have you got any ideas?

Comment: You cleaned out your cookies on your IE.  So you are testing under a different condition, or the old cookie expired.